# Objective-C: Pass a map snapshot to view controller in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkmapsnapshotter

I'm trying to segue from a `mapView` to a page that contains a snapshot of a chosen location on that mapView.

Here is my `prepareForSegue` method:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"LocationConfirmSegue"]) {
        LocationConfirmationViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;

        MKCoordinateSpan span;
        span.longitudeDelta = mapFocusSpan;
        span.latitudeDelta = mapFocusSpan;

        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.center = *currentPinLocation;
        region.span = span;

        MKMapSnapshotOptions *options = [[MKMapSnapshotOptions alloc] init];
        options.region = region;
        options.size = CGSizeMake(270, 180);

        MKMapSnapshotter *snapshotter = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions:options];
        [snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:    ^(MKMapSnapshot * _Nullable snapshot, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
                return;
            }

            vc.mapSnapshot = snapshot.image;
        }];
    }
}
```

I can pass information to the destination VC fine outside of the snapshotter's completion handler. The code all works fine, too––snapshot.image does indeed return a UIImage*––however it's not being passed to the destination view controller. When I try to access the mapSnapshot property in that view controller, I get (null).

Comment: One possible solution I can think of would to just pass the "options" to the destination view controller and generate the snapshot there. That feels like a hack, though, and an alternative (where I don't have to import MapKit in the destination view controller) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of generating the snapshot in `prepare(for:)`, I would initiate the snapshot where you are presently initiating the segue, and then once the snapshot has been generated, trigger the segue from the completion block of the snapshotter

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of Apple's OpenGLES screenshot to prevent the inability to get a layer image of the map or a black screen

```
-(UIImage *)zjcCutScreenImage {
NSInteger myDataLength = self.width * self.height * 4; 
GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
glReadPixels(0, 0, self.width, self.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
for(int y = 0; y <self.height; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x <self.width * 4; x++){
        buffer2[(JSNDHC - y) * self.width * 4 + x] = buffer[y * 4 * 1024 + x];
    }
}
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, myDataLength, NULL);
int bitsPerComponent = 8;
int bitsPerPixel = 32;
int bytesPerRow = 4 * self.height;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(self.width, self.height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
return myImage;
}
```